# Why am I getting this java.lang.NumberFormatException?

Tags: java

I have written the following code where I am declaring a string, extracting the numbers, and then assigning it into a variable `result` where I am trying to convert the numbers from `String` into `Integer`. However, I am getting an exception called `java.lang.NumberFormatException`. How do I avoid this exception?

My code is as follows. Can anyone explain?

```
package trialprogram;
public class Interviewaskedq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String S1="12SERT34";
        String alpha=" ";
        String num=" ";
        for(int i=0;i<=S1.length()-1;i++)
        {
            char ch=S1.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(ch))
            {
                alpha=alpha+ch;
            }
            else if(Character.isDigit(ch))
            {
                num=num+ch;

            }
        }

        int result = Integer.parseInt(num); 
    }
}
```

Comment: because first character in num variable is space. Replace `String num=" "` with `String num=""`

Comment: the space in `String alpha = " ";` is probably also not intended...

Comment: Wow..Thank you so much Carlos.That worked! :) Danke Schon :)

Answer (score 5):

You're starting your `num` String with a blank space `" "`. Since any String like `" 12345"` is not a number, then you have the problem.

Try `String num = "";` instead.